# Sorting a deque with class objects

Tags: c++, class, sorting, deque

I have a question about sorting a deque with class objects. So I have one deque called "rq" which holds, multiple types of data. I want to sort the deque by comparing the TAU values. However, I keep getting insane compiler errors when trying to sort the deque. Below is the the function I tried to do in order to compare TAU values and sort the deque. How would i go about solving this problem?

```
 deque<system>rq 
 //and so on
 struct tauSort
 {
     bool operator ()( system &a,  system  &b)
     {              
         return a.getTau() < b.getTau();        
     } 
 }

 //Blah Blah
 system sorting;
 sort(rq.begin(), rq.end(), sorting)
```

Comment: You miss a lot of semicola there.

Comment: he's also missing `const`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This:

```
system sorting;
```

should be this:

```
tauSort sorting;
```

because you want to pass the sorting functor, not a `system` object. And you are forgetting a semicolon at the end of the `sort` statement too.

You can also simply do:

```
sort(rq.begin(), rq.end(), tauSort());
```

Not to mention that you can pass the `system`s by constant reference in your function, since you don't need to modify them. And it's better for you to make the `operator()` const as well:

```
bool operator ()(system const& a,  system const& b) const { … }
```